# apt-get update error in kali linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I tried really hard to figure out the solution but whenever I type `apt-get update` I get:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Get:2 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid InRelease [7,140 B]
Err:2 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: 7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139
Err:3 http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
403  Forbidden

Reading package lists... Done

W: GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139

E: The repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid InRelease' is not signed.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1

W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1

W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1

W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1

W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1

W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1

W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
```

My sources.list file contains:

```
#The Kali Repository

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20171109-13:49]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20171109-13:49]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free



deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

# deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

I researched really hard and did many online fixes but nothing happened.

Can somebody please suggest a fix to this? Thank you.

Comment: The first 5 numbers of this question's URL ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have more than one issue currently. Your original issue seems to have been lack of a correct gpg signature. If you are prepared to trust the site, navigate to the url at the error message, ie. https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian, where you will see three *.asc files. Try running `apt-key add` on the one for the package you are using.

A second issue you seem to be having is that you are using an incorrect url, ie. http://repo.kali.org/kali for something.

A third issue is that you seem to have some form of duplication on line 13 of your `sources.list` file. If it isn't too long, please post it.

Finally, there does exist an official kali linux forum website https://forums.kali.org/ that might be helpful for you to join.

Comment: The third issue is that a new release of VirtualBox has dropped its repository info into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`, so the existing line for it (line #13) in `/etc/apt/sources.list` is now a duplicate and should be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much user1404316 and telcoM for your sincere answer, the source.list is as follows:     

#The Kali Repository

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official 

Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20171109-13:49]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20171109-13:49]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

# deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

Comment: Also @user1404316 can you please elaborate the 'apt-key add' step and the other two solutions to the two issues.

Comment: You posted your `sources.list` as a comment instead of editing it into your question, so it's not very readable. In any event, the link I gave you for the Kali Linux forum should point you to the most specific answers and the best experts.